# Non-nullable instance field '_repository' must be initialized

Tags: flutter

I'm a beginner in flutter, and trying to follow a tutorial.
I'm stuck in the below error :

I have the below code in chat_service.dart that is used to get an API from Laravel/Mysql :

```
import 'package:buschat/repository/repository.dart';

class ChatService {
  Repository _repository;
  ChatService() {
    _repository = Repository();
  }

  getAllChats() async {
    return await _repository.httpGet('get-all-chat');
  }
}
```

I'm receiving the following error in `ChatService()` method:

```
Non-nullable instance field '_repository' must be initialized.
Try adding an initializer expression, or add a field initializer in this constructor, or mark it 'late'
```

The tutorial is working fine, and it's one year old.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try....

```
class ChatService {
  Repository _repository = Repository();
  ChatService() {
    getAllChats();
  }

  getAllChats() async {
    return await _repository.httpGet('get-all-chat');
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, will test it and mark as answered soon.

Answer (score 1):

Because of null-safety, all variables must be initialized unless they are marked as nullable. So you need to either give a value to your variable or use late keyword which means you need give it value later but you can't use it as null:

```
late Repository _repository;
```

or

```
// not recommended use (you need to use dependency injection)
Repository _repository = Repository();
```

You can also mark you variable nullable so you can use it as null:

```
Repository? _repository;
```